# npm http-server keeps caching my App.js

Tags: caching, npm, httpserver

I'm learning AngularJS. I'm using npm http-server to run the project locally.

The problem is, whenever I make changes to App.js the change doesn't get reflected on the site. I try refreshing the page, it doesn't update the changes to JS. I also tried **http-server -o -c-1** and still it doesn't refresh the cache.

The only thing that makes the App.js update is clearing the browser cache. How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try to use live-server instead. It works for me.

npm install live-server -g

And you can start it simply by the command live-server.

Comment: This works flawlessly. The site even updates as soon as I save the file changes, no need to refresh. Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 27):

Sorry a little late to the party,

When using npm http-server

just append -c-1 to the start command e.g.

```
npm http-server -c-1
```

[Documentation http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Weird that it didn't work for OP 

Comment: i deleted some files and started the server with this command. it restored deleted files.... i didnt ask for that

Comment: `-c-1` is not working for me either :( despite this being the documented solution.

Comment: -c-1 does not work at all

Comment: Make sure your browser is not caching the respective files css js. I am using chrome and the dev tools need to be open f-12 and the don't cache while dev tools open.

Comment: if http-server is installed globally theres no need to prefix with npm or npx, but -c-1 is the correct answer!

Comment: Idk but if this doesnt work. Maybe try to clear the **cache in your Browser** first. \ 
For Chrome > From here, you’ll want to find the Refresh button next to the address bar:  4005  Click `Empty Cache and Hard Reload` in the list of options, and you’re done. \ 
https://nira.com/chrome-clear-cache/